# react native how to call more than one funcion on a single event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to call two functions within setState function of React native ,
I think its Possible and I think that there is only error in my syntax 
so could you please correct my code , cancelationButnEdit function is not runing I am debuging with simple console.log , there is no output at all , i guess because its not accessing the function .

```
....
const list = this.state.data;
         list[index] = task;
         this.setState({data : list},
             () => { this.cancelationButnEdit()},
              () => {this.saveTaskList()});
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not call both function from the same callback? Because `setState` has only one callback as it's second parameter. So you have to write it in this way:

```
this.setState({
                data : list
              }, () => {
                 this.cancelationButnEdit(); 
                 this.saveTaskList()
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to to all your functions calls in on call back

```
  const list = this.state.data;
  list[index] = task;
  this.setState({data : list}, () => {
           this.cancelationButnEdit()
           this.saveTaskList()
         });
```